# Probablistic interpretation of linear regression

Tags: regression

In Andrew Ng's [notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf), he states that $p(e^{(i)}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}exp \left( \frac{-(e^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)$ implies $ p(y \mid x; \theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} exp\left( \frac{(y - \theta^T x)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right)$ . 
I would like to know how does the first equation imply the second one. 
Unlike [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/111957/193736)  question I am not interested in knowing why we choose $p(y^{(i)} \mid x^{(i)})$, instead I want to understand how we reached there or how is $p(\epsilon) = p(x,y;\theta) = p(x \mid y; \theta) = p(y \mid x; \theta) $.

Comment: I understand that  $p(\epsilon) = p(y - \theta^Tx) $, but I do not know how to proceed from there.

Comment: As I wrote: this $\epsilon$ is calculated given that you know the input $x$ and parameters $\theta$. You assumed that the error is Gaussian earlier. So, this defines how $y$ is distributed given the inputs and parameters, hence, it's distribution of $y$ conditioned on them

Comment: Might this contain the answer you are looking for? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305908/likelihood-in-linear-regression

Answer (score 0):

The superscript $(i)$ plays no role here, so let's drop it to reduce clutter.

The first equation implies the second one because of the assumption that $x$ is independent of $\epsilon$. In the probabilistic formulation, we define $y:=\theta^Tx+\epsilon$ and seek the conditional density of $y$ given $x$. (In the notes, $\theta$ is assumed a nonrandom constant.) The result follows from:

> Claim: Suppose $X$ and $W$ have joint density $f_{X,W}(x,w)$, and define $Y:=X+W$. Then the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X,W}(x, y-x).$$ Corollary: If in addition $X$ and $W$ are independent, then the conditional density of $Y$ given $X$ is $$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = f_W(y-x).$$

using $X:=\theta^Tx$, $W:=\epsilon$, $Y=y$.

The claim can be proved using the change of variables (Jacobian) formula, while the corollary is an application of the definition of conditional density.